# Range check error while painting the canvas

Tags: delphi

I got a Range check error in this piece of code:

```
{ This procedure is copied from RxLibrary VCLUtils }
procedure CopyParentImage(Control: TControl; Dest: TCanvas);
var
  I, Count, X, Y, SaveIndex: Integer;
  DC: HDC;
  R, SelfR, CtlR: TRect;
begin
  if (Control = nil) OR (Control.Parent = nil)
  then Exit;

  Count := Control.Parent.ControlCount;
  DC    := Dest.Handle;
  with Control.Parent
   DO ControlState := ControlState + [csPaintCopy];

  TRY
    with Control do
     begin
      SelfR := Bounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
      X := -Left; Y := -Top;
     end;

    { Copy parent control image }
    SaveIndex := SaveDC(DC);
    TRY
      SetViewportOrgEx(DC, X, Y, nil);
      IntersectClipRect(DC, 0, 0, Control.Parent.ClientWidth, Control.Parent.ClientHeight);
      with TParentControl(Control.Parent) DO
       begin
        {$R-}
        Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND, DC, 0); <--------------- HERE
        {$R+}        
        PaintWindow(DC);
       end;
    FINALLY
      RestoreDC(DC, SaveIndex);
    END;

    { Copy images of graphic controls }
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
      if Control.Parent.Controls[I] = Control then Break
      else if (Control.Parent.Controls[I] <> nil) and
        (Control.Parent.Controls[I] is TGraphicControl) then
      begin
        with TGraphicControl(Control.Parent.Controls[I]) do begin
          CtlR := Bounds(Left, Top, Width, Height);
          if Bool(IntersectRect(R, SelfR, CtlR)) and Visible then
          begin
            ControlState := ControlState + [csPaintCopy];
            SaveIndex := SaveDC(DC);
            try
              SetViewportOrgEx(DC, Left + X, Top + Y, nil);
              IntersectClipRect(DC, 0, 0, Width, Height);
              {$R-}              
              Perform(WM_PAINT, DC, 0);  <--------------- HERE
              {$R+}
            finally
              RestoreDC(DC, SaveIndex);
              ControlState := ControlState - [csPaintCopy];
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  FINALLY
    with Control.Parent DO
     ControlState := ControlState - [csPaintCopy];
  end;
end;
```

Somebody released the code without having the Range Check activated :(

I put {$R-}{$R+} around the lines that are generating the error and the code is working now but I am not sure what are the consequences. I don't want some strange error later.

---

Delphi, Win 7 32bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Perform` procedure expects its second parameter to have type `WParam`, which is a signed integer type. As of Delphi 3, the `HDC` type of the actual parameter is unsigned (as are most other handle types). It's common on NT-based systems for handles to have values that are higher than MaxInt, which is outside the range for `WParam`. That's the source of your range-check error.

Type-cast the argument and you will be fine:

```
Perform(wm_EraseBkgnd, WParam(DC), 0);
```

The `Perform` method will simply interpret the high unsigned value as a large negative value instead. It will send the parameter value to the message handler, and the message handler will type-cast it back to the `HDC` type it wants. All the types are the same size, so there is no danger.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked. I have seen the difference between the parameters but I had no clue that I can typecast using WParam. It looks like the changed appeared in Delphi 3 but the code was intended for Delphi 2005 and I initially thought is an error in code. Probably the developer had the Range Check option turned off.

Answer (score 2):

It should be OK, it's the usual Cardinal/Integer typecast. WM_ERASEBKGND is used like this all over the VCL, for instance in Controls.pas, with the {$R-} directive.

Comment: Hi. I already tried Integer. It didn't worked. +1 for explanations.

Comment: I mean, either you explicitly typecast as Rob suggested, or you use {$R-} like you did and like it is done in the VCL (esp. Controls.pas).